# DOING_AJAX php version issues

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, version

I am getting this notice with PHP 7.4.12 version ****: Use of undefined constant DOING_AJAX - assumed 'DOING_AJAX' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in****

And with PHP 8 I am getting this error ***Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "DOING_AJAX" in***

It is the second line in this function that is causing it. ( *if (!is_admin() || (defined(DOING_AJAX) && DOING_AJAX)) {* )

```
private function init() {
    if (!is_admin() || (defined(DOING_AJAX) && DOING_AJAX)) {
        $this->frontend = new Woo_Custom_CSV_Builder_Frontend();
    }
    if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
        //$this->handle_download();
    }
}
```

Could someone point to right direction with this issue?

Comment: PHP 8 got a lot more particular about errors and no longer lets you get away with things that were reported as warnings in previous versions

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined) states out the usage of the `defined` function: `defined(string $constant_name): bool`.

You have to give a string as the parameter of defined. In your case a constant is given. In earlier PHP versions this was okay although this is an obvious error.

Just use the following:

```
if (!is_admin() || (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)) {
   ...
}
```